# Difficulty installing a package in R linux, dalton_rqi

Tags: r, rstudio

Downloaded package from below URL.
Attempted to install using below command; response shown.

```
library(dalton.rqi,lib.loc='/home/X/Desktop/')
Error: package ‘dalton.rqi’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

https://my.clevelandclinic.org/departments/anesthesiology/depts/outcomes-research/risk-quantification

It appears this is a compiled package that maybe I don't have the source for? Is there a way to force install of the package? I'm unable to install using Rstudio GUI in its current form as a zip. Tried repackaging to tar.gz has Rstudio was looking for and also had a non-zero exit status error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the package prior to installation?

Comment: The package is not currently installed, so no package to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this can't be achieved directly. The error message says it well: to use a package in R it needs to be built on an R version matching yours.

I can suggest two ways to move forward:

1. Contact the authors, ask for the R *sources* (it is somewhat surprising they did not make them available in the first place), and build the package yourself.
2. Downgrade your R version as far back as needed to match the one this pre-built package used.

Comment: One suggestion on point (2), I wouldn't necessarily characterize this as "downgrading R". R is designed so that you can run multiple versions at the same time for reasons just like this. So maybe something like "Install a second, older version of R" would be less scary to somebody than having to "downgrade".

Comment: @Adam AFAIK the free versions of RStudio do not support easy switching between multiple installed R versions - but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: RStudio (the IDE) will use whatever R version it finds in the `${PATH}`, Just a matter of setup script to switch if you really need that.  For example on my Linux box with R-devel tucked away, if I do `PATH="/usr/local/lib/R-devel/bin/:${PATH}" rstudio` I get the RStudio desktop happily running R-devel (from that directory prefixed to `${PATH}`.  Nothing more to it.   Would be the same on other OSs.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel true, I was talking about this: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/212364537-Using-multiple-versions-of-R-with-RStudio-Workbench-RStudio-Server-Pro

Comment: (In any event, does not help OP as a Google search suggests that `dalton.rqi` is likely a commercial / closed-source package, and a Windows binary for R before 3.0,.0 may be hard to find these days.  Such is life...)